# Call to a member function on none-object when persisting cascade

Tags: symfony

im trying to persist a collection form ...
weird thing is that the code was working on 2.0 but not in 2.2 (my be im wrong but im pretty sure it was)

here is the relevant part of the code ..

error

```
Error: Call to a member function setEventId() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\new\src\Splurgin\EventsBundle\Entity\SplurginEventEvents.php line 317
```

in my form type

```
    ->add('packages' , 'collection', array('type'=>new SplurginEventPackagesType(),
                                            'allow_add'    => true,
                                            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
```

my events entity **where the error is**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Splurgin\EventsBundle\Entity\SplurginEventPackages", mappedBy="eventId" ,cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $packages;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->media = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->packages = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getPackages()
    {
        return $this->packages;
    }

    public function setPackages($packages)
    {

        $this->packages = $packages ?: new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->packages as $package) {
            $package->setEventId($this); // line of error
        }
        return $this->packages;
    }
```

my packages entity

```
/**
 * @var integer $eventId
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SplurginEventEvents", inversedBy="packages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $eventId;
/**
 * Set eventId
 *
 * @param integer $eventId
 */
public function setEventId(\Splurgin\EventsBundle\Entity\SplurginEventEvents $eventId)
{
    $this->eventId = $eventId;
}

/**
 * Get eventId
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getEventId()
{
    return $this->eventId;
}
```

packages type

```
class SplurginEventPackagesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('price')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('items')

        ;
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Splurgin\EventsBundle\Entity\SplurginEventPackages',
        );
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'packages';
    }
}
```

in my controller there is nothing interesting just checking if form is valid and persisting it.

update : i have already updated the js file

```
The placeholder was changed from $$name$$ to __name__ in Symfony 2.1
```

update2 : seems that i need to add , add and remove functions .. but im not sure though

update 3 : added the add and remove methods (just as in the documentation) , but still i get the same error but in the add method

here is the code for the add method , and the only code that has been changed is the setPackages method

```
    public function getPackages()
    {
        return $this->packages;
    }
    public function addPackage( ArrayCollection   $package) // if i put the type hinting i get an error that array collection was not passed , i get a normal array instead
    {
        $package->setEventId($this); // this thoughs an error (because we cant use set event method on an array 
        $this->packages->add($package);
    }
    public function removePackage(ArrayCollection  $package)
    {
//...
    }
    public function setPackages($packages)
    {

        $this->packages = $packages ;

        return $this->packages;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your `SplurginEventPackagesType` form.

Comment: What is in C:\wamp\www\new\src\Splurgin\EventsBundle\Entity\SplurginEventEvents.php before and after line 317 ?

Comment: @codeiz as I expected problem was in `SplurginEventPackagesType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after lot's (and i mean alot ) of hair pulling this is the problem

in the packages type

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Splurgin\EventsBundle\Entity\SplurginEventPackages',
    );
}
```

should be

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Splurgin\EventsBundle\Entity\SplurginEventPackages',
    ));
}
```

this would sound stupid , but i guess i need to get some sleep , huh